# Typecasting array object

Tags: iphone, xcode

I struct at a point in my application.I have an array object called time and a global int variable as index..so when I need to use both I need to type cast array object to integer value.How can I do this?Please help..

```
NSArray *time=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1.08",@"1.12",@"1.14",@"1.18",@"1.20",@"1.24",@"1.25",@"1.29",@"1.30",@"1.34",@"1.45",@"1.50",@"1.51",@"1.55",@"1.56",@"2.00",@"2.01",@"2.06",@"2.07",@"2.11",@"2.12",@"2.16",@"2.17",@"2.21",nil];
index = 0;
```

```
[self performSelector:@selector(startAnimation) withObject:self afterDelay:[time objectAtIndex:index]];
```

This is my code,but it is giving error and telling to typecast

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `[[time objectAtIndex:index] floatValue]`. The objects in array are strings and you can get the float value by calling `[myStr floatValue]`. You can also use `doubleValue` here.

Comment: @taskinoor How do I get the maximum or minimum value in that case ? I won't be able to do [time.@"@max.keyPathToProperty"] is there a way to do that ?

Comment: @Farini, not sure what you are asking, and it does not look like a question related to this original question. You can ask a new question so that people can answer that.